# Is there a feature in matplotlib histogram that can plot relative probability?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a normalized histogram using python. I am using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.randn(1000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, density=True)
```

The `density=True` parameter makes the area under the curve equal to 1. This can be verified by:

```py
print(np.sum(n)*np.diff(bins))
# 1.0
```

But I do not want this. What I am looking for is a feature that can plot the bars as relative probability. What I mean by this is `np.sum(n)` should be equal to 1.

I know such a feature exists in MATLAB: `histogram(x, 'Normalization', 'probability')`.

My question then is: does such a feature exist in matplotlib? If not, how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, the idea of `stacked` is that when you have several plots, they will be "stacked", instead of going side by side. See plots here https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html

I ran it with two data sets and `stacked` doesn't seem to change the output values itself, only graphical representation.

If you run

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
hist = plt.hist([x,y], density=True, stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Then both x and y will be normalized, I believe that's what was meant in a part of documentation that you've quoted.

Either way, you cannot achieve both (1) sum of values = 1 (2) sum of values, multiplied by bin width = 1,  unless width of a bin is equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you. I think your statement "Then both x and y will be normalized..." makes sense.

In MATLAB, histogram plot can be normalised using either of the following two [properties](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram-properties.html): `'Normalization', 'probability'` and `'Normalization', 'pdf'`.

Now matplotlib seems to support the later kind of normalistation. Is the former way supported as well in any way?

Comment: I guess `density=True, cumulative=True` is what you're looking for.

Comment: No. I don't think so. 

Using the above parameters in MATLAB gives me this [plot](https://imgur.com/a/yXL6UMq). 

Here, blue bars are using parameter `pdf` and orange bars are using `probability`. The later bars have sum = 1.

Comment: I am not using Matlab, but I am sure that's something you can figure out yourself, or ask people in Matlab community.